# Cannot automate Html canvas using Appium

Tags: html5-canvas, appium, mobile-website, browser-automation

I am trying to automate mobile web testing in a emulator Nexus 5 , but I am not able to do the click the textbox and enter words for the login and password. The Login page is in html canvas. 
I tried to use by.id / xpath but still cannot work. 
I am using Eclipse and Java.

Please help...

I have tried these two in Esclipse

// new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gameDiv']")),i,j).click().perform();
            new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gameDiv']")),i,j).click().sendKeys("abc");

Below is html canvas code :

I am not sure whether is my coordinates are wrong , I tried to use a loop but no response on the emulator, only the program is running. Please kindly provide some idea...

Comment: Below is the html canvas code : <canvas id="egretCanvas" width="480" height="800" style="width: 480px; height: 800px;"></canvas>

Comment: <input id="egretInput" type="text" tabindex="-1" style="width: 1px; height: 12px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; border: none; padding: 14px 0px; outline: thin; background: none; overflow: hidden; word-break: break-all; opacity: 0; font-family: 微軟正黑體; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; font-size: 20px; color: rgb(138, 133, 129); vertical-align: middle; line-height: 20px;">